# Installed barcode plugin did not show in palette

Tags: eclipse, barcode, birt, report-designer

I have installed Birt barcode plugin in my BIRT Report Designer.
But it did not show in my palette. I downloaded the jar from [here](http://www.onbarcode.com/tutorial/java-barcode-eclipse-birt.html) and installed it in my plugin. After  that I restarted all of my programs but then it still did not show. Am I missing something?

here is where I installed the jar and did not show.
[barcode jar directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lceUG.png)

and here is the items inside the plugins
[image]

Comment: needed comments guys I'm still working on it.

Comment: What did you mean by _"installed it in my plugin."_? Copy the JAR to the `plugins` folder does not work, you have to copy the JAR into the `dropins` folder instead.

Comment: @howlger Hi, but where can I find the dropins folder? it does not exist in my birt folder. Anyway, I posted the picture of items inside the plugins maybe it could help.

Comment: Your screenshot shows the `birt\plugins` directory, but is there a `birt\dropins` directory?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no dropins directory hmm..

Comment: In this case, please check in _Help > About Eclipse: Installation Details_, tab _Plug-ins_ if the plug-in has been installed. If not, look in the _Error Log_ (or if you have not this view, in the `.metadata\.log` file in your workspace) view for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the barcode plugin you are using is not compatible in the current version of BIRT you are using.  Look for updated Barcode plugin.

Comment: I was thinking about that. I was looking for an updated jar but did not find any as of now.